# Upgrading and using pip2 and pip3

Tags: python, python-2.7, hash

I have installed 2 version of python (2.7.11 and 3.4.4) on my windows 7 machine.

When I use:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I get the following error:

> Hash of the package
>   https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=2056f553d5b593d3a970296f229c1b79(fromhttps://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/)(64b61606117b334f0ec6fcb63d8e4fa7)
>   doesn't match the expected hash 2056f553d5b593d3a970296f229c1b79!Bad
>   md5 hash for package
>   https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=2056f553d5b593d3a970296f229c1b79
>   (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/)

or when i want install cython on version of 2.7 by `pip2 install cython`, show me this:

> Hash of the package
>   https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/C/Cython/Cython-0.23.4-cp27-none-win32.whl#md5=9bbeca3a08f62804229c807f5ec99d2b
>   (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cython/)
>   (43077163dafe55831fef3ec713aa7846) doesn't match the expected hash
>   9bbeca3a08f62804229c807f5ec99d2b!Bad md5 hash for package
>   https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/C/Cython/Cython-0.23.4-cp27-none-win32.whl#md5=9bbeca3a08f62804229c807f5ec99d2b
>   (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/cython/)

However I dont have problems when installing cython on the 3.4.4 version with `pip3 install cython`.

What is meaning above errors? And how I can upgrade my pips (pip2 and pip3)?

Comment: You could try `pip install --upgrade --no-use-wheel pip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a option that might help,

> --no-use-wheel
>
> Do not Find and prefer wheel archives when searching indexes and
>   find-links locations.